# What is the equivalent for this cURL request in axios

Tags: vue.js, curl, flask, axios

What is the equivalent axios request for cURL request below?

```
curl -X POST \
  http://159.89.90.5:5000/users/login \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "email": "pwerner@gmail.com",
    "password": "password"
}'
```

I've tried using axios request as follow:

```
        let axiosConfig = {
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
          }
        };

        this.$http.post('http://159.89.90.5:5000/users/login', {"email": "pwerner@gmail.com", "password": "password"}, axiosConfig)

        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            currentObj.output = error;
        });
```

but I keep getting CORS error because the request doesn't fit with the request I made in cURL above. What am I missing here? if correct like curl request above I'll get email parameter with value pwerner@gmail.com

below is the error I've got when trying to make the request:
[image]

but if I use formData instead of using json for the same code, it works, and my server (flask framework) is already provided header: response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") for solving CORS issue

Comment: can you post the exact error?

Comment: CORS is an error specifically thrown in browsers, which is basically a security measure that only accepts HTTP requests to resources that are explicitly allowed.

Comment: @depperm I've edited the question & provide the screenshot error I received

Comment: Well you can see the exact error and it tells you exactly what is going wrong

Comment: @Flame as I explained in the question, I have provided header for CORS and it seems the server doesn't receive equivalent axios request with curl request I've provided & generated error, if I'm using formData in axios instead of JSON it works well meaning no CORS issues, that's why I believe the problem in making request

Comment: idk try testing the CURL response and see if it actually returns the header. There are some other intricacies like OPTIONS method (pre-flight). I suggest looking up how CORS works and go from there.

Comment: @Flame the CURL above is working perfectly in terminal and I'm looking for the equivalent in axios request

Comment: That CORS response header is missing from the response to the preflight OPTIONS request. This is a separate request sent by the browser under certain circumstances to check whether the server will allow the main request. In this case the preflight will be triggered by the `Content-Type` being `application/json`.